# Wordpress - SQL Query

Tags: wordpress

Im trying to write a query to get all posts that are in a certain category that have been posted in the last 60 days, but im unsure as to where to find category information on posts in the database.

There doesnt seem to be any info in the wp_posts table.

Could someone help me form this query, im quite confused.

Cheers,

Comment: Are you trying to do this in MySql, or in a wordpress template (which one)?

Comment: Sorry, im trying to do this in a wordpress template

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the post table doesn't have categories is because all that is done through the [taxonomy system](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) ([more info](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/wordpress/essential-guide-wordpress-custom-taxonomies/)) (which takes a few minutes to get your head around).

You can just use [query_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts) function to query posts from a specific category (see category__in on the linked page). That takes the headache out of taxonomy query.

Alternatively, if you don't want to mess with the main loop (which query_post will), you can create an instance of [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) and loop through them with that.

**Edit**: [This page might also interest you](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2793/sql-query-to-select-posts-from-multiple-categories)